# R: Different colours for barplot labels

Tags: r

I have a barplot and would like to have the label showing different colours and the bars to be grey.

I tried:

```
col_lab <- c("red","green","grey","red","red","blue")

barplot(1:6,names.arg=1:6,main="barplot",las=1,horiz=TRUE,col="grey",xaxt="n",col.names=col_lab)
```

but I got an error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: replace `col="grey"` by `col = col_lab`. Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: I would like the bars to be grey but each of the labels to have the colour specified.

Comment: The parameter you're looking for is `col.axis` rather than `col.names` (not sure where you got that) but it doesn't allow length>1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yaxt="n"` and do an `mtext`. To get the right positions, use the coordinates `barplot` throws invisibly.

```
b <- barplot(1:6, names.arg=1:6, main="barplot", las=1, horiz=TRUE, col="grey", 
             xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
mtext(1:6, 2, .5, at=b, las=2, col=col_lab, font=2)
```

[image]